# Attribute table field default value not transfering to new edited features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, editing, fields-attributes, database

Using ESRI ArcMap 10.0, in a versioned environment,  we are in a geo-database and have a feature class with a default value populated in field properties. When we create a new feature using editing tools the default value is not populating the corresponding field as it should.  Has anyone encountered this problem before and any ideas for solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the cause, but here are some things to check by on; without more details about the dataset and environment, it's really just shots in the dark though.  My first though would be to check if the dataset in question has subtypes.  If there are subtypes, you can set default field values in the fields tab of the FC properties all day and it won't do a darn bit of good unfortunately (this has caused me a fair bit of frustration before, so don't think you're alone).  If there are sub-types, you need to go into the properties for each subtype and set the default field values you want for each field for each subtype.

Second, I would go back in to the datasets properties and just double checking that the defaults saved correctly (I know manually assigning domains after a field has already been created for example often doesn't work and you have to do it with the GP tool instead of through the FC/table properties box).

Next, as basic as it may sound, I'd go double check that the assigned default values match with the field type for each field with a default value assigned.  Obviously a default value of "ABC" would have an issue being stored in a short integer field (if it would even let you save the properties like that, not sure...).

Next, I would open a brand-new MXD and bring the dataset in question in and start editing and test it there.  If it works correctly with defaults there but not elsewhere, it is likely that you already had brought the dataset into the MXD before you assigned the defaults and it had already auto-set-up create feature templates for you with the default values (or lack of defaults) that were assigned at the time.  If that is the case, you can either remove the dataset from the MXD and re-add it (this will loose layer properties like labeling and symbology), or you can edit the create feature templates in the MXD to use user defined default values.  More on that at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003w2000000.htm

If none of that works, I'd try it with a different feature class or the same feature class copied to a different database, like a new/empty FileGDB (drag and drop from within ArcCatalog and it should carry over domains, defaults, etc...) and see if there is something about the feature class or database in question that is corrupted.

Finally, if none of the above help, I'd either contact ESRI tech support or re-post your question with significantly more detail about exactly what your having issue with (ex: what version or ArcServer is it, what Database version is it at, what field types & feature class type are you having issue with, what default values aren't working, are some defaults saving and not others or are no defaults saving, etc...).

Hope one of the suggestions helps.